# Advanced sibling selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't quite get my head around this. I have the following construct:

```
<div class="container">
     for n = 0 to ...
         <a href="some url">Link n</a>
     endfor

     for each link in ".container"
          <div class="poptip"></div>
     endfor
</div>
```

And an example could be:

```
<div class="container">
     <a href="some url">Link 1</a>
     <a href="some url">Link 2</a>
     <a href="some url">Link 3</a>

     <div class="poptip">Some content related to link 1 retreived with ajax</div>
     <div class="poptip">...</div>
     <div class="poptip">...</div>
</div>
```

Now the hurdle, I am trying to show the `.poptip` on hover on the anchor tag, and this obviously works fine if there is one link (which is usually the case). In any case where there's >1 link, then the last one will work. Current css (sass style) which doesn't quite work in >1 cases:

```
.producttooltip {
  position: relative;
}
.producttooltip a:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
```

I cannot change the structure of the html, it will always be container > all links followed by all poptips. I can however mark the poptips and anchor tags up with unique identifiers e.g. `<a href="some url" rel="identifier">Link 1</a><div class="poptip" rel="identifier"></div>`, but I can't quite figure out if I in css can create a general selector which goes (pseudo):

```
a:hover + div[rel=a.rel] {
    display: block
}
```

So my question is, can I get this construct marked up in pure CSS, or do I have to use some JS trickery (which I can, but I would really prefer CSS). Hope one of you guys are more clever than me.

Edit: *just gonna clarify - I **cannot** change the structure of the html. The neatest solution would obviously be to wrap each element with it's equivalent poptip, but my entire conundrum is the fact that I cannot do this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can do this way:

```
$('a').on('hover', function() {
  $('.poptip').eq($(this).index()).show();
}, function() {
  $('.poptip:visible').hide();
});
```

It is tough to do this with CSS alone. But even then, I have provided a CSS solution below. Do have a look if you wanna consider a CSS only solution.

---

You can do this via CSS itself. Although there are lot of plugins, lets do something like this. First, you need a hovering element, say in this case, a link.

```
<a href="#">Hover Me!</a>
```

Next should be the tool tip. We can have a `<span>` for now and put it inside the link.

```
<a href="#">Hover Me!<span class="tooltip">Hello, World!</span></a>
```

Now comes the real CSS part.

```css
a span {display: none; position: absolute; color: #fff; background: #000; padding: 5px;}
a {position: relative;}
a:hover span {display: block; text-align: center;}
```

**Snippet**

```css
a span {display: none; position: absolute; color: #fff; background: #000; padding: 5px;}
a {position: relative;}
a:hover span {display: block; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover Me!<span class="tooltip">Hello, World!</span></a>
```

This is just one of a pure CSS solution. You can see the working [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/acyNw/1/).

---

However, there are a lot of plugins, which keep this concept as base and work for hover-cards and tool tips. Some good examples include:

- [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)
- [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)
- [HoverCard](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard)
- [40+ Tooltips Scripts With AJAX, JavaScript & CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/06/12/tooltips-scripts-ajax-javascript-css-dhtml/)

Comment: Questioner says *I cannot change the structure of the html, it will always be container > all links followed by all poptips.*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This is just a guide for starting. Okay, I can add a specific answer for this too. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: As stated, I cannot alter the structure. Your solution would have been the pretty and easy (correct even) one though.

Comment: @Dennis Yes I have updated my answer. Have a look please. I was insisting, if you get a chance to change the structure, you can use the CSS solution. I have provided a jQuery solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery solution**

You can use `mouseenter/mouseleave` event in order to show up the desired elements

```js
$('a').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  $('.poptip').eq(i).show();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('.poptip').hide();
});
```

```css
.poptip { 
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <a href="some url">Link 1</a>
     <a href="some url">Link 2</a>
     <a href="some url">Link 3</a>

     <div class="poptip">Some content related to link 1 retreived with ajax</div>
     <div class="poptip">Some content related to link 2 retreived with ajax</div>
     <div class="poptip">Some content related to link 3 retreived with ajax</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `jquery` this can be achieved easily, just need to get the `index` of the current anchor element & display the respective `div` present at the index location.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="some url">Link 1</a>
  <a href="some url">Link 2</a>
  <a href="some url">Link 3</a>

  <div class="poptip">Some content related to link 1 retreived with ajax</div>
  <div class="poptip">...</div>
  <div class="poptip">...</div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$(function(){
   $('a').on('hover',function(){
      var ind = $('a').index(this);
      $('.poptip').eq(ind).css('display','block');
   });
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/yks8upvw/)